# No aplicar hover hasta que el elemento no esté en determinada posición

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Tengo un menú lateral `#elemIzq` que está posicionado a la izquierda de la pantalla. Le he puesto un `left: -295px` para que sea oculto, y así mostrar todo el contenido con un click, de izquierda a derecha.

Ahora estoy trabajando con la función `hover`, para que una vez que el ratón esté fuera del navegador, vuelva a esconderse.

El problema es que no quiero que se aplique ese `hover`, hasta que el elemento no haya cogido la posición `left: 0px.` ¿Podría hacerlo?

Código:

---

```
 $('#elemIzq').hover(function () {}, function () {
     $("#elemIzq").removeClass("desplegado");
 });
```

(La clase `desplegado` es la que le hace tener una posicion `left: 0px`).

Comment: en la funcion `hover` prueba a añadir una condición que mire la posicion de elemento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo usaría $.animate() para animar el lateral y así lanzar la animación cuando termine.
Para ocultar el menú usaría el segundo callback de $.hover()

```js
$('#elemIzq').hover(
    function(){
        $("#elemIzq").stop().animate({width:200}, 400, 'swing', function(){
            $("#elemIzq").removeClass("desplegado");
        })
    }, function(){
        $("#elemIzq").stop().animate({width:100}, 400, 'swing', function(){
            $("#elemIzq").addClass("desplegado");
        })
    }
)
```

```css
#elemIzq{
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  color: white;
}
#elemIzq.desplegado{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elemIzq" class="desplegado">
  HOVER ME
</div>
```

[Ejemplo en CodePen](https://codepen.io/Jandrito8/pen/qxomOw)

*Edito: Añado el .stop(), que hace que la animación se termine en el momento en que sales de pantalla.

Comment: Buenas Jandro. Te he editado la respuesta para añadir el codigo para probar aqui mismo y asi no es necesario ir a otra pagina para verlo :P  Un saludo

Comment: Genial. Aunque llevo tiempo registrado es la primera vez que empiezo a usar esta plataforma. Lo tendré en cuenta para próximas aportaciones.

Comment: Hay muchas *cositas* a las que ir cogiendo el tranquillo asi que paciencia hahah analiza la respuesta en modo `edit` para ver como funciona los snippets de codigo.  ^^

Answer (score -1):

Puedes evaluar la posición de un elemento de la siguiente manera (jQuery):

**scrollLeft()** Sets or returns the horizontal scrollbar position of selected elements

**scrollTop()** Sets or returns the vertical scrollbar position of selected elements

Por lo que puedes obtener la posición vertical y horizontal. Cuando obtengas el valor que tu consideres puedes aplicar el hover o realizar la acción que deseas.

Saludos

Comment: Hola Armando. Para mejorar la respuesta, pon todo el texto en español. Y pon un ejemplo del codigo resultante con la condicion para que se aplique el `hover` o no. Para más info mira [answer]. Un saludo